# How do I get the content through API (link) in node Js

Tags: javascript, api

im having a hard time how to get a content from this API. API is accessed by this link https://evilinsult.com/generate_insult.php.

more info about API:
https://evilinsult.com/api/
https://github.com/EvilInsultGenerator/website

Comment: You should avoid providing external links. Make your question clear and post your code attempts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.